# Next.js route mismatch in prod build but not in dev

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js and trying to implement incremental static regeneration. My pages structure is:

```
pages
- [primary]
  - article
    - [...slug.js]
```

and my [...slug.js]

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Article({ post }) {
    if (!post) {
        return 'loading'
    }
    const data = post[0];
    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto pt-6">
            <Head>
                <title>{`${data.title.rendered}`}</title
            </Head>
            <main>
                <div>{data.content.rendered}</div>
            </main>
        </div >
    )
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {

    return {
        paths: [{ params: { primary: '', slug: [] } }],
        fallback: true,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const slug = params.slug[0];
    const res = await fetch(`https://.../?slug=${slug}`)
    const post = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { post },
        revalidate: 1,
    }
}
```

This works locally when I pass route like: `localhost:3000/dance/article/lots-of-dancers-dance-in-unison`, it correctly passes the slug and I can query the CMS no problem. But when I run build I get:

`Error: Requested and resolved page mismatch: //article /article at normalizePagePath`

Answer (score 2):

This is because the static path you are providing for primary is '' (empty).

For empty string value for primary, the static path becomes //article which resolves to /article. This is what the error says.

Though this works in development, it will give the said error in Prod build.

Add a value to the path and it should work!

> paths: [{ params: { primary: ***'abc'***, slug: [] } }],